# How to make a new application for the existing developer?

Tags: iphone

I have a developer account in iOS provisioning portal and already have all the certificates for one application. Now I want to build a new application with a new app ID within the same account.

Should I have to repeat all the steps once more? Can anybody help me with the steps I need to do in iOS provisioning portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your certificate remains the same. (Developer / Distribution).

1. Create a new app id specific your new application
2. Create a new provisioning profile Specific for this application using new app id you created in above step. Select existing dev or distribution certificate. Select devices you want your app to be installed on for debugging / AdHoc builds.

Comment: R u saying that i just need to make another app id in the portal.And just need to create one appstore and adhoc provisioning profiles and down load it and then drag it to my xcode is it ok

Answer (score 0):

yes. you will have to repeat it for the new apps except developer/distribution certificates this is because of independency of your applications that one of your application setting doesn't affect other's.

other push notification certificate will aslo separate for separate apps. both of distribution and development